# Can the XCode editor do HTML tag completion

Tags: xcode, editor

I am experimenting with Ruby and Rails on OS X, using the XCode text editor as the "IDE". The one feature I am missing, so far, is the ability to have HTML tags automatically closed. In other words, if I enter a `<p>` tag, then the `</p>` closing tag gets entered automatically.

Can the XCode text editor do this?

Comment: Believe me, you want something like Coda to do this. Xcode + HTML = hell.

Comment: Do you use Coda for RoR? I've heard that most of the features that make Coda great don't apply in a RoR environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just spelunking through my old questions and realized I never got an answer to this one.

I eventually decided to go with RubyMine as my main Rails IDE. TextMate was my second choice, but it does not have split screen viewing, which I really really need.